# RxSwift Generic parameter type inference error

Tags: swift, swiftui, rx-swift, urlsession

I am trying to make a API resquest using RxSwift. My`SwiftUI view has the signUp()` method which calls the API request method in View Model. However when calling the method, I am getting the error as `Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred`. What is the correct way to do this?

```
func signup() {

    var signupDictionary = [String: Any]()
    signupDictionary.updateValue(firstName.lowercased(), forKey: "firstName")
    signupDictionary.updateValue(lastName.lowercased(), forKey: "lastName")
    signupDictionary.updateValue(userLatitude, forKey: "latitude")
    signupDictionary.updateValue(userLongitude, forKey: "longitude")
    signupDictionary.updateValue(email.lowercased(), forKey: "emailId")

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    do {
         try signUpViewModel.postRequestData(input: signupDictionary) // Error: Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
            .subscribe (onNext: { model in
                print(model)
        },
        onError: { error in
                print(error)
        },
        onCompleted: {
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }catch {
        
    }
}
```

Below function from View Model will hit the API Client and retrieve data.

```
func postRequestData<T, U: Codable>(input: T)  -> Observable<U?> {
    let signupURL = URLConstants.baseUsersURL + URLConstants.userSignUp
    return client.postRequest(data: input, urlString: signupURL)
}
```

Comment: Any is not Codable, probably you need `signupDictionary = [String: String]`

Comment: Yes, Is there any work around for it? Since latitude and longitude values in this case has to be Double. Hence Dictionary needs to be [String: Any]

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the Dictionary. It is exactly what the error says it is. The compiler has no way of knowing what type `U` should be and neither do we. So what type are you expecting `U` to be?